# How to migrate Redis RDB file created with a module to a deployment without that module? (RedisGraph no longer in Redis Stack versions 7.2+)

Tags: database, redis, database-migration, compatibility, graph-databases

When I try to load a Redis database with Redis Stack 7.2 from an RDB file which has been created with a prior version of RS, it does not load, printing this error:

```
* Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.13
* RDB age 848231 seconds
* RDB memory usage when created 1.50 Mb
# The RDB file contains AUX module data I can't load: no matching module 'graphdata'
```

This is likely due to Redis phasing out RedisGraph, the [article about that](https://redis.com/blog/redisgraph-eol/) mentions RG "is no longer a part of Redis Stack from version 7.2".

I was assuming it's all fine, as I have never used any graph related functionality. However, the RDB file seemingly references the RedisGraph module **despite** not having any entries related to it, which I see no logical reason for.

What is the intended way for users to keep their Redis Stack version up-to-date, if they need RDB persistence? Seems like version 7.2 will simply not accept any RDB file from any previous version.

Is there a simple way to migrate it and keep using this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This got me too. In particular, I've been using redis-stack for a little project locally and the Homebrew cask updated from redis-stack-server 6.2.6-v9 to 7.2.0 a week ago ([commit](https://github.com/redis-stack/homebrew-redis-stack/commit/18859030edd11c8ce5f9d2290b01ce9678c4d337)).

The reason we can't load our RDBs, even though we never used RedisGraph, is that loading the module saved metadata to the RDB in AUX fields (custom data types?), which the new version of Redis can't read without the module. This also disallows you from unloading the module at runtime with [`MODULE UNLOAD`](https://redis.io/commands/module-unload/).

This is wack and they're talking through a fix in pull requests [#11056](https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/11056) and now [#11374](https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/11374).

Anyway, a basic strategy for rescuing your data is to load it up in the previous working configuration, export it as a plaintext AOF log in a way that doesn't include the offending references to the old module, upgrade to 7.2.0 again—having deleted the offending RDB file—and load in the AOF we generated. `SAVE` and you've got a fresh RDB.

I'm working locally with about 5 MB of data and there's no production instance to keep available. This approach assumes there are no clients connecting and trying to modify data except for you. So here's a basic outline, but modify for your situation.

1. **Make a backup of your RDB file** before you do anything else, so you have a safety net if these steps don't work precisely on the first try. For me, with Homebrew, I just did e.g.
   `cp /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis-stack/dump.rdb ~/Desktop/dump.orig.rdb`
2. Downgrade back to 6.2.x. Again, this will depend on your OS and configuration. For Homebrew, you can attempt to downgrade a cask by downloading the version of the formula you want and installing it from disk. I downloaded [the previous version of the cask formula for redis-stack-server.rb](https://github.com/redis-stack/homebrew-redis-stack/blob/fd3e0973bc32685b07fbbf4b9f5fc8123ab907ab/Casks/redis-stack-server.rb), then
   `brew install --cask ~/Downloads/redis-stack-server.rb`
3. Try starting `redis-stack-server`. You should be back.
4. We can see those problematic references to the module by inspecting the RDB file, btw:

   ```
   $ redis-check-rdb /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis-stack/dump.rdb
   [offset 0] Checking RDB file dump.rdb
   [offset 27] AUX FIELD redis-ver = '6.2.13'
   [offset 41] AUX FIELD redis-bits = '64'
   [offset 53] AUX FIELD ctime = '1692437664'
   [offset 68] AUX FIELD used-mem = '5479248'
   [offset 84] AUX FIELD aof-preamble = '0'
   [offset 96] MODULE AUX for: graphdata
   [offset 111] MODULE AUX for: scdtype00
   [offset 124] MODULE AUX for: ft_index0
   [offset 129] Selecting DB ID 2
   [offset 2666081] MODULE AUX for: graphdata
   [offset 2666096] MODULE AUX for: scdtype00
   [offset 2666108] Checksum OK
   [offset 2666108] \o/ RDB looks OK! \o/
   [info] 4713 keys read
   [info] 0 expires
   [info] 0 already expired
   ```
5. Export your data.

   ```
   $ redis-cli
   127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET aof-use-rdb-preamble no
   OK
   127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET appendonly yes
   OK
   127.0.0.1:6379> BGREWRITEAOF
   Background append only file rewriting started
   ```

   Check the server log for that to finish, then disconnect the client and stop the server.
6. Delete the active RDB file.
   `rm /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis-stack/dump.rdb`
   There should be a larger `appendonly.aof` alongside it now. You can move that somewhere safe.
   `mv /opt/homebrew/var/db/redis-stack/appendonly.aof ~/Desktop/appendonly.6.2.aof`
7. Upgrade back to 7.2.0. For me, using Homebrew, that's just
   `brew upgrade redis-stack-server`.
8. Finally, start 7.2.0 without any data (since we deleted/moved it all away)
   `redis-stack-server`
   And replay the log:
   `redis-cli --pipe < ~/Desktop/appendonly.6.2.aof`

You can now issue a `SAVE` or `BGSAVE` to generate a new RDB file.

---

I hope this helps! I haven't been in charge of a production Redis instance in a decade or so, and I just chose Redis Stack for the JSON support, because I'm caching entire responses from a JSON API and thought it might be handy. But this issue with module interoperability makes me wonder whether I should just stick with vanilla Redis for now.

By the way, Redis 7.2.0 says this on startup for me:

```
71950:M 21 Aug 2023 04:07:05.933 * <redisgears_2> Created new data type 'GearsType'
71950:M 21 Aug 2023 04:07:05.934 * <redisgears_2> Detected redis oss
71950:M 21 Aug 2023 04:07:05.934 # <redisgears_2> could not initialize RedisAI_InitError

71950:M 21 Aug 2023 04:07:05.934 * <redisgears_2> Failed loading RedisAI API.
71950:M 21 Aug 2023 04:07:05.934 * <redisgears_2> RedisGears v2.0.11, sha='0aa55951836750ceabd9733decb200f8a5e7bac3', build_type='release', built_for='Macos-mac os12.6.3.arm64v8'.
71950:M 21 Aug 2023 04:07:05.935 * <redisgears_2> Registered backend: js.
71950:M 21 Aug 2023 04:07:05.935 * Module 'redisgears_2' loaded from /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v0/lib/redisgears.so
```

So... I assume that's fine. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It seems like a very complex process, but it does indeed work, and is the only way to go, until the dummy module mentioned in the other answer is officially deplyoed as part of Redis Stack. 

I am marking this correct, as it's an immediate solution, but for anyone reading this later than some weeks after @Lior Kogan's answer, it likely will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I'm from Redis. **We are sorry for this.** We will fix it soon (the target date is set for next week).

We plan to release a new dummy module - RedisCompat. This module will be minimalistic. It will support no commands and will ignore graph data upon loading. If there is an empty graph AUX field - the module will ignore it and continue. If there are graph keys - the module will fail (users with graph keys would have to delete them manually before they can upgrade to Redis Stack 7.x. This will ensure graph data won't be deleted unintentionally).

We will also release a patch for Redis Stack 7.2 that will include the RedisCompat module.

If you are using Redis with RedisGraph and would like to remove RedisGraph because of the end-of-life but still want to keep all your other data, you would be able to add the RedisCompat module manually.

And lastly - we'll fix RedisGraph to not store a graph AUX field when there are no graph keys.

---

Update, October 2023:

- [Redis Stack Server 7.2.0-v5](https://github.com/redis-stack/redis-stack/releases/tag/v7.2.0-v5): "Fix for the "The RDB file contains AUX module data I can't load: no matching module 'graphdata'" error message when upgrading Redis Stack"
- RedisCompat: https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/RedisCompat
- Fix in RedisGraph: https://github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph/pull/3185 (included in v2.10.15 and v2.12.9)

Comment: Thank for the explanation of the causes and plans for fixing it, as well as the attention to fixing this issue! 

I can only mark one answer as correct, but I am glad there will soon be a "it just works" solution instead of the many steps needed to take otherwise.