# Redis Stack Server could not started because of missing module

Tags: redis, redis-stack-server

I tried to install redis-stack-server on my ubuntu server.

I followed redis official guide on 'https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/install-stack/linux/'

But... When I started redis-stack-server I got this error.

```
1938:M 09 Sep 2023 15:05:29.698 # The RDB file contains AUX module data I can't load: no matching module 'graphdata'
```

So... When I tried to access redis-cli, I got this error, because redis-stack-server failed to start.

```
root@localhost:~# redis-cli

Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused

not connected>
```

I searched Google about this error. But, unfortunately, I could not find any clue.

Should I install any other modules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like the error you get when an existing RDB file uses a module that the Redis you are running doesn't have. Graph was removed from Redis Stack recently. Are you upgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting dump.rdb file.
But I'm not sure it is right approach.

And, I found simular thread.

[How to migrate Redis RDB file created with a module to a deployment without that module? (RedisGraph no longer in Redis Stack versions 7.2+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76928167/how-to-migrate-redis-rdb-file-created-with-a-module-to-a-deployment-without-that)